# Antivirus program

Tags: python

I have always been known to write really sloppy code. Can someone help me rewrite the following code in a neater manner?

```
import os
import hashlib
import sys
import time

file_list = []

rootdir = "C:/"

print("Program starting!")
print("[+]Collecting virus definitions and allocating memory[+]")

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        #print os.path.join(subdir, file)
        filepath = subdir + os.sep + file

        if filepath.endswith(".exe") or filepath.endswith(".dll"):
            file_list.append(filepath)
            #print(filepath)

print("[+]Virus definition and memory allocation complete...[+]")
print("[+]Starting scan...[+]")
def countdown():
    for x in range(4):
        print(x+1)
        time.sleep(1)

countdown()

def Scan():
    infected_list = []
    for f in file_list:
        virus_defs = open("VirusLIST.txt", "r")
        file_not_read = False
        print("\nScanning: {}".format(f))
        hasher = hashlib.md5()
        try:
            with open(f, "rb") as file:
                try:
                    buf = file.read()
                    file_not_read = True
                    hasher.update(buf)
                    FILE_HASHED = hasher.hexdigest()
                    print("File md5 checksum: {}".format(FILE_HASHED))
                    for line in virus_defs:
                        if FILE_HASHED == line.strip():
                            print("[!]Malware Detected[!] | File name: {}".format(f))
                            infected_list.append(f)
                        else:
                            pass
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Could not read file | Error: {}".format(e))
        except:
            pass
    print("Infected files found: {}".format(infected_list))
    deleteornot = str(input("Would you like to delete the infected files (y/n): "))
    if deleteornot.upper() == "Y":
        for infected in infected_list:
            os.remove(infected)
            print("File removed: {}".format(infected))
    else:
        print("Executed with exit code 0")
        os.system("PAUSE")
Scan()
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation about what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: Checking executables against hashes is a really outdated (and honestly pretty useless) approach to antivirus software...

Answer (score 10):

> ```
> rootdir = "C:/"
> ```

What operating system is this for? It's not correct for Windows -- Windows is supposed to use the `\` character as a path separator. Sometimes you are using `os` as is recommended, sometimes you roll your own. This is not good.

I think the scan directory ought to be a parameter, not a constant hardcoded in the program. Then put it together with `os.path.join()`. Why did you not use it?

> ```
> for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
>      for file in files:
>         #print os.path.join(subdir, file)
>         filepath = subdir + os.sep + file
>
>         if filepath.endswith(".exe") or filepath.endswith(".dll"):
>             file_list.append(filepath)
>             #print(filepath)
> ```

- What's the purpose of the commented-out lines?
- Why do work before you know if the file is one that you need to scan? Only build the temporary string if you need it.
- This doubly-nested loop could, and probably should, be rewritten as a one line list comprehension.

> ```
> print("[+]Virus definition and memory allocation complete...[+]")
> print("[+]Starting scan...[+]")
>
> def countdown():
>      for x in range(4):
>          print(x+1)
>          time.sleep(1)
> countdown()
> ```

- This function is called `countdown` but it actually counts up. Why?
- Why is it declared in the middle of imperative coden? Is there any benefit to declaring it and then immediately using it?
- If you want the numbers from 1 to 4, ask for them. `range()` can take a second parameter to indicate a range.

> ```
> def Scan():
> ```

- I note you're using global variables. This is a bad practice. Use function parameters instead.

> ```
> infected_list = []
>     for f in file_list:
>         virus_defs = open("VirusLIST.txt", "r")
> ```

- So, you open and read through the entirety of `VirusLIST.txt` for each file on your hard drive. Does this seem right to you? Perhaps there's a data structure you should be using.
- Please use a more descriptive name for your loop index variable than `f`

> ```
>    file_not_read = False
> ```

- This is confusing. Most people don't deal with double negatives easily. What does this variable actually represent? When does it change from `False` to `True`?

> ```
>    print("\nScanning: {}".format(f))
> ```

- Have you heard about the new formatted string syntax? In this line it would be `f"Scanning: {f}"`

> ```
>    hasher = hashlib.md5()
>          try:
>             with open(f, "rb") as file:
>                 try:
> ```

- You should just have the outer `try:`, and catch the appropriate exception rather than catching everything.

> ```
>    buf = file.read()
>      file_not_read = True
>      hasher.update(buf)
> ```

- I don't think the temporary variable is necessary

> ```
>    FILE_HASHED = hasher.hexdigest()
> ```

- Please choose another variable name. This one implies that the variable contains a file; it does not. Also, why is the variable name in all caps?

> ```
>    print("File md5 checksum: {}".format(FILE_HASHED))
>      for line in virus_defs:
>          if FILE_HASHED == line.strip():
>              print("[!]Malware Detected[!] | File name: {}".format(f))
>              infected_list.append(f)
> ```

- Why do you keep on scanning the rest of the virus definitions if the file is already known to be infected?

> ```
>     else:
>           pass
>       except Exception as e:
>           print("Could not read file | Error: {}".format(e))
>    except:
>       pass
> ```

- Why are you swallowing all the exceptions here? What is the potential benefit of this?

  ```
  print("Infected files found: {}".format(infected_list))
  deleteornot = str(input("Would you like to delete the infected files (y/n): "))
  ```
- `input()` returns a `str` , so why convert it?

> ```
>     if deleteornot.upper() == "Y":
>         for infected in infected_list:
>             os.remove(infected)
>             print("File removed: {}".format(infected))
>     else:
>         print("Executed with exit code 0")
> ```

- What's the reason for this? You are not actually using an exit code; the output is a lie.

> ```
>        os.system("PAUSE")
> ```

- Not cross platform.

> ```
>  Scan()
> ```

- You should have [a main guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) around this.